# Spark DataFrame operators (nunique, multiplication)

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I'm using jupyter notebook with pandas, but when i use Spark, i want to use Spark DataFrame to convert or computation instead of Pandas. Please help me convert some computation to Spark DataFrame or RDD.

DataFrame:

```
df =
+--------+-------+---------+--------+
| userId | item  |  price  |  value |
+--------+-------+---------+--------+
|  169   | I0111 |  5300   |   1    |
|  169   | I0973 |  70     |   1    |
|  336   | C0174 |  455    |   1    |
|  336   | I0025 |  126    |   1    |
|  336   | I0973 |   4     |   1    |
| 770963 | B0166 |   2     |   1    |
| 1294537| I0110 |  90     |   1    |
+--------+-------+---------+--------+
```

**1. Using Pandas computing:**

```
(1)  userItem = df.groupby(['userId'])['item'].nunique()
```

and result is a Series object:

```
+--------+------+
| userId |      |
+--------+------+
|  169   |   2  |
|  336   |   3  |
| 770963 |   1  |
| 1294537|   1  |
+--------+------+
```

**2. Using multiplication**

```
data_sum = df.groupby(['userId', 'item'])['value'].sum()  --> result is Series object

average_played = np.mean(userItem)  --> result is number

(2)  weighted_games_played = data_sum * (average_played / userItem)
```

Please help me using Spark DataFrame and Opertors on Spark to do this (1) and (2)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can achieve (1) using something like the following:

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as f
userItem=df.groupby('userId').agg(f.expr('count(distinct item)').alias('n_item'))
```

and for (2):

```
data_sum=df.groupby(['userId','item']).agg(f.sum('value').alias('sum_value'))

average_played=userItem.agg(f.mean('n_item').alias('avg_played'))

data_sum=data_sum.join(userItem, on='userId').crossJoin(average_played)

data_sum=data_sum.withColumn("weighted_games_played", f.expr("sum_value*avg_played/n_item"))
```

Comment: I mean is multiplication between Series object in pandas, but with Spark I can't

( 
**weighted_games_played = data_sum * (average_played / userItem)**
)

Comment: gotcha, I will amend the answer

Comment: glad to hear it

Comment: for those looking for just a plain (non `groupby`ed `nunique`), just do `df.agg(f.expr('COUNT (DISTINCT <col_name>)'))`.

Answer (score 0):

You can define method like below:

```
import org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.distributed.{RowMatrix}
import org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.{Vectors,Matrices,DenseVector}
import org.apache.spark.sql.types.{StructType,StructField,DoubleType}
import org.apache.spark.{SparkConf,SparkContext}
object retain {
  implicit class DataFrameTransforms(left: DataFrame) {
  val dftordd = left.rdd.map{case row => 
  Vectors.dense(row.toSeq.toArray.map{x=>x.asInstanceOf[Double]})}
  val leftRM = new RowMatrix(dftordd)
    def multiply(right:DataFrame):DataFrame = {
      val matrixC = right.columns.map(col(_))
      val arr = right.select(array(matrixC:_*).as("arr")).as[Array[Double]].collect.flatten
      val rows = right.count().toInt
      val cols = matrixC.length
      val rightRM = Matrices.dense(cols,rows,arr).transpose
      val product = leftRM.multiply(rightRM).rows
      val x = product.map(r=>r.toArray).collect.map(p=>Row(p: _*))
      var schema = new StructType()
      var i = 0
      val t = cols
       while (i < t) {
        schema = schema.add(StructField(s"component${i}", DoubleType, true))
       i = i + 1
       }
      val err = spark.createDataFrame(sc.parallelize(x),schema)
err
}
}
}
```

and before using just

```
import retain._
```

say you have two dataframes called df1(m×n) and df2(n×m)

```
df1.multiply(df2)
```